# What Is the Location for Each Fight Pattern?

Tags: rainbow-moon

As the title suggestions, I'm looking for the location of each fight pattern.  The dungeon or location name alone would be great.

Some of the dungeons are very, very long and I haven't fully explored them.  I'm trying to avoid going through each one again in order to find the patterns I'm missing.  In particular, those dungeons with teleporters...